# yum + does not update installed package

Tags: rhel, yum, upgrade

we are trying to install the following rpm ( that actually already installed )

```
rpm -qa | grep sshpass
sshpass-1.06-2.el7.x86_64


yum install sshpass-1.06-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Examining sshpass-1.06-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: sshpass-1.06-1.el7.x86_64
sshpass-1.06-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do

echo $?
1
```

but its returned `exit code 1`

why yum not ignoring the rpm that already installed and returned error?

other example

```
rpm -qa | grep figlet
figlet-2.2.5-9.el7.x86_64



yum install figlet-2.2.5-9.el7.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
configuration
Examining figlet-2.2.5-9.el7.x86_64.rpm: figlet-2.2.5-9.el7.x86_64
figlet-2.2.5-9.el7.x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do


echo $?
1
```

note - we also try `yum clean all` ,

and removed the `/var/cache/yum/*`

but not help

Comment: Do you want to (perhaps) *reinstall* the package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am under the impression that you are complaining about yum default behavior.

yum serves as a package manager that installs/removes or upgrades packages.

If there's `Error: Nothing to do` it is de-facto failing a task to install / remove or upgrade a package - hence return code == 1.

If you would like to check if the package is installed and if it is not then install it try the following :

`rpm -qa | grep wget || yum -y install wget`

This should give you $? == 0 in the standard scenario.

Comment: This doesn't work. `rpm -qa lololol` will return `0` even though no such package is installed, at least on Red Hat 7. You need to do something like `rpm -qa | grep wget` to check for a given package.

Comment: @JM0 yeah that's true - thanks for the heads up - I'll fix it in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to install packages that are either older than or the same version as what you already have installed on your system. `yum` checks for this before it operates which is why it is giving the messages when you attempt to use it with those packages. Otherwise, what would `yum` do during updates? If an update came out and was available in one of the repos, would it upgrade them both to the latest and have two of the exact same package on the system?

If you need an older version of software, then you need to compile it from source instead of using `yum` to install its `rpm`.

Comment: figlet-2.2.5-9.el7.x86_64 is the same version this isnt old version !!!

Comment: @yael I've explained that. It's the same version that you already have on the system. The version of `ssh-pass` is older than what you have on the system. That is why `yum` is giving the message in both cases. Why are you trying to install the same exact version that you already have?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue while installing a package and the problem was the same version of the package already existed.

The solution which worked for me:
Lets say the package name is: package-abc

```
sudo yum remove package-abc -y

sudo yum install package-abc -y
```

Hope this helps you too!
Cheers!